# Fire click event of li before hiding ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox and then an unordered list like below:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" />
    <button>Go</button>
</div>
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

Now in the blur event of textbox:

```
$('input').on('blur', function() {
    $('ul').hide();
});
```

The above code works just fine.

I am trying to make something like `combobox`.

So, my desired behavior is :

When Textbox loses focus, suggestions should hide (which is shown above)

When Clicked on a suggestion, its click event should fire and then text of that suggestion should be filled in textbox and then all suggestions should hide

So, for the second functionality, when I click on any `li` the `click` event of `li` should fire and then `ul` should be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var items = ["Apple", "Banana", "Celery", "Peach", "Plum"];

$('input').on('input', function() {
  var text = $(this).val();
  $('ul').show().empty().append(items.filter(function(item) {
    return item.match(new RegExp(text, 'i'));
  }).map(function(text) {
    return $('<li>').text(text);
  }));
});

$('input').on('blur', function() {
  $('ul').fadeOut();
});

$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
  $('input[type=text]').val($(this).text());
  $('ul').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="text" />
    <button>Go</button>
</div>
<ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Try to click on Apple.

Comment: @Vishal Fixed. BTW, this isn't keyboard accessible. Depending on your exact need, you might just want to use `combobox`

Comment: I would not use timeout as my ul may have a scroll bar. And if user scrolls then after timeout ul may disappear. Still I will try it before asking you something else. BTW thanks for the answer.

Comment: That works great even with scroll bar. Thanks you made my day.

Comment: fadeOut does not work the way I expected. Your previous answer with setTimeOut works great.

Answer (score 0):

Simply update the textbox and then hide the ul within the same click event of the li.

```
$("li").on("click", function() {
  $("input[type=text]").val(this.text());
  $("ul").hide();
});
```

Sorry if the jQuery isn't perfect--I don't use it that often. This should help, anyway.

Comment: I have tried that before asking the question. When I click on li, textbox has already lost its focus, so ul is hidden and inturn li is hidden, so li click is not  firing.

Comment: Oh, okay. I didn't get that from the post. Looks like you've got a solution anyway. ^^

Comment: Yes, I got the solution. Thanks for help.